# Table Border Setting

Tags: html, border, tablelayout

How to set table border or table's outside border with some color and size but the cells of the table have border `size=0`?

```
  ----------------------
 |   -------   ------   |
 |  |   1   | |  2   |  |
 |   -------   ------   |                      
 |                    3 |
  ----------------------
```

- container 1 & 2 : which are the cells have  border=0
- container 3 : which is the table itself has border=1 * color = #333333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mnzN2/2/

Here's a working example.

Answer (score 2):

Should use CSS IMO

```
    table#foo {
        border:1px solid #333333;
    }

    table#foo td { 
        // td styles
    }

    //etc

<table id="foo"> <!-- table code -->
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table style="border: 1px solid red;">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

This works in the newest Firefox and Chrome. Is there any particular browser you're having problem with?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in IE, too.

```
<table style="border:1px solid red;"> 
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr> 
</table>
```